# Block Internet Explorer Traffic except specific ip's

Tags: networking

In my company we got some applications that need features
from IE, so I can't "kill" it completely.

Since Internet Explorer has reached EOL, is there a way to
**block traffic** from Internet Explorer except for
specific IPs by using the Windows Firewall?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You won't need to kill it, MS are going to kill it for you. This has been in the pipeline for many years; plenty of time to re-write software that uses out-of-date protocols.

Comment: @Tetsujin I know but it is still a major security concern.

Comment: Running protocols only supported by IE is itself a major security concern, which is why they should have all been re-written years ago.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your comment but how would you determine with a proxy which browser is used? Or application in general

Comment: @Mingebag - You can enforce the use of a proxy with IE and exclude the use of the proxy with Chrome and Firefox.  You don't determine which browser is used, you configure the browser to use that proxy, and use a group policy to enforce it's use.

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable in two steps :

1. In the Firewall "Outbound Rules" section, create a New rule
   of type Program that blocks all for IE
2. Create another Custom rule for IE that allows these specific IPs.

The problem with this method is that the Firewall evaluates
Block rules before Allow rules, so the Allow rule must be defined
of higher priority.
Such rules are called "Authenticated Firewall Bypass rules".

To achieve that, when creating the Allow rule,
on the Action page, select "Allow the connection if it is secure",
click "Customize", then select "Override block rules".

The result will be the total block of IE, except for the
specified IPs.

References :

- [Order of Windows Firewall with Advanced Security Rules Evaluation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc755191(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Authenticated Firewall Bypass](https://www.goconqr.com/p/165965/note_page/13043)